# Raising errors with User Defined Functions (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I created a User defined Function in vba to calculate profits according to First in - First out inventory system. Before moving to the real code, I want to make a few checks on weather the input is valid or not.

```
'---------------Check Information for errors----------------------
    SellSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(SellQuantity)
    BuySum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(BuyQuantity)
    
    
    SellPCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(SellPrice)
    SellQCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(SellQuantity)
    BuyPCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(BuyPrice)
    BuyQCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(BuyQuantity)

    
    If SellSum > BuySum Then                                        'More sales than inventory, throw error
        FIFO_PROFIT = VBA.CVErr(XlCVError.xlErrValue)
    End If
    
    If (BuyPCount <> BuyQCount Or SellPCount <> SellQCount) Then    'Incomplete data, throw error
        FIFO_PROFIT = VBA.CVErr(XlCVError.xlErrValue)
    End If
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

And after the real code, I have the final value,

```
FIFO_PROFIT = RunningProfit
```

But,when I entered invalid data, that should have raised the errors, it didn't do anything. It was like it just skipped the error checking and jumped to the actual code.

The actual code is a little lengthy and I don't believe it to have any relation with it. But if anyone wants to review it,
https://pastebin.com/fA2pY52f

Comment: Is it me or you are overwriting the FIFO_PROFIT value at the end? It won't come out as an error if you overwrite it, will it? In such case just add a `GoTo` inside each of your If statements that checks for error and redict the code to the end of the function.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey, Yes you are correct, I was overwriting because I thought that was the only way it would work. Let me check your solution and hit you up with if it worked or not. +1 for quick response

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey, how would that work exactly ? If(condition) goto End Function ????

Comment: [rtfm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/cverr-function) , accessed by pressing F1 key when cursor is on method you don't know (CVErr), But you can [Raise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/raise-method) a real error! And use [Option Explicit](https://riptutorial.com/de/excel-vba/example/3554/verwenden-sie-immer--option-explicit-)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say something like this might work:

```
Function FIFO_PROFIT(SellPrice As Variant, SellQuantity As Variant, BuyPrice As Variant, BuyQuantity As Variant) As Variant
'Calculate the Profit according to the FIFO method
 
 
'---------------Check Information for errors----------------------
    SellSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(SellQuantity)
    BuySum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(BuyQuantity)
    
    
    SellPCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(SellPrice)
    SellQCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(SellQuantity)
    BuyPCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(BuyPrice)
    BuyQCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(BuyQuantity)
 
    
    If SellSum > BuySum Then                                        'More sales than inventory, throw error
        FIFO_PROFIT = VBA.CVErr(XlCVError.xlErrValue)
        
        'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        GoTo FIFO_PROFIT_IS_ERROR '<--------------------ADDED CODE (1 of 3)X
        'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        
    End If
    
    If (BuyPCount <> BuyQCount Or SellPCount <> SellQCount) Then    'Incomplete data, throw error
        FIFO_PROFIT = VBA.CVErr(XlCVError.xlErrValue)
        
        'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        GoTo FIFO_PROFIT_IS_ERROR '<--------------------ADDED CODE (2 of 3)X
        'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    End If
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
 
'--------------MoreVariables--------------------------------------
Dim RunningSale As Variant
Dim RunningBuy As Variant
Dim RunningCost As Variant
Dim RunningBuyQuantity As Variant
Dim RunningSales As Variant
Dim RunningProfit As Variant
Dim Residual As Variant
Dim UsedupResidual As Variant
Dim y As Variant
 
y = 1
RunningCost = 0
Residual = 0
UsedupResidual = 0
RunningSales = 0
RunningProfit = 0
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
    For x = 1 To SellQCount
    
    If y <> 1 Then                                                                  'BUGtest
    
        RunningBuyQuantity = Residual + BuyQuantity(y).Value2
    End If
            While (RunningBuyQuantity <= SellQuantity(x).Value2 And y <= BuyQCount) 'Bugtest
                    
                If y = 1 Then
                    RunningCost = RunningCost + (BuyPrice(y).Value2 * BuyQuantity(y).Value2)
                Else
                    RunningCost = RunningCost + ((BuyPrice(y).Value2 * BuyQuantity(y).Value2) + (BuyPrice(y - 1).Value2 * Residual))
                End If
                
                Residual = 0
                RunningBuyQuantity = RunningBuyQuantity + BuyQuantity(y).Value2
                y = y + 1
                
            Wend
        
        If RunningBuyQuantity > SellQuantity(x).Value2 Then
            Residual = SellQuantity(x).Value2 - RunningBuyQuantity
            UsedupResidual = BuyQuantity(y).Value2 - Residual
            RunningCost = RunningCost + (UsedupResidual * BuyPrice(y).Value2)
        End If
        
        RunningSales = SellPrice(x).Value2 * SellQuantity(x).Value2
        
        RunningProfit = RunningProfit + RunningSales - RunningCost
        
        RunningSales = 0
        RunningCost = 0
        
    Next x
    
    FIFO_PROFIT = RunningProfit
    
'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
FIFO_PROFIT_IS_ERROR:     '<--------------------ADDED CODE (3 of 3) X
'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    
End Function
```

I've taken your whole function and added 3 lines of code. I didn't check the code itself, so no evalutation about it. In the two cases (more sales and incomplete data) the FIFO_PROFIT is correctly set as you already did and then the `GoTo` instruction send the code to the FIFO_PROFIT_IS_ERROR line, conveniently placed at the end of the function. More information about the `GoTo` instruction [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/goto-statement).

Then again, you could also use the `Exit Function` instruction. It would not need the third line FIFO_PROFIT_IS_ERROR and it would also work. It would result in this:

```
Function FIFO_PROFIT(SellPrice As Variant, SellQuantity As Variant, BuyPrice As Variant, BuyQuantity As Variant) As Variant
'Calculate the Profit according to the FIFO method
 
 
'---------------Check Information for errors----------------------
    SellSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(SellQuantity)
    BuySum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(BuyQuantity)
    
    
    SellPCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(SellPrice)
    SellQCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(SellQuantity)
    BuyPCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(BuyPrice)
    BuyQCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(BuyQuantity)
 
    
    If SellSum > BuySum Then                                        'More sales than inventory, throw error
        FIFO_PROFIT = VBA.CVErr(XlCVError.xlErrValue)
        
        'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        Exit Function '<--------------------ADDED CODE (1 of 2)X
        'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        
    End If
    
    If (BuyPCount <> BuyQCount Or SellPCount <> SellQCount) Then    'Incomplete data, throw error
        FIFO_PROFIT = VBA.CVErr(XlCVError.xlErrValue)
        
        'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        Exit Function '<--------------------ADDED CODE (1 of 2)X
        'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        
    End If
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
 
'--------------MoreVariables--------------------------------------
Dim RunningSale As Variant
Dim RunningBuy As Variant
Dim RunningCost As Variant
Dim RunningBuyQuantity As Variant
Dim RunningSales As Variant
Dim RunningProfit As Variant
Dim Residual As Variant
Dim UsedupResidual As Variant
Dim y As Variant
 
y = 1
RunningCost = 0
Residual = 0
UsedupResidual = 0
RunningSales = 0
RunningProfit = 0
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
    For x = 1 To SellQCount
    
    If y <> 1 Then                                                                  'BUGtest
    
        RunningBuyQuantity = Residual + BuyQuantity(y).Value2
    End If
            While (RunningBuyQuantity <= SellQuantity(x).Value2 And y <= BuyQCount) 'Bugtest
                    
                If y = 1 Then
                    RunningCost = RunningCost + (BuyPrice(y).Value2 * BuyQuantity(y).Value2)
                Else
                    RunningCost = RunningCost + ((BuyPrice(y).Value2 * BuyQuantity(y).Value2) + (BuyPrice(y - 1).Value2 * Residual))
                End If
                
                Residual = 0
                RunningBuyQuantity = RunningBuyQuantity + BuyQuantity(y).Value2
                y = y + 1
                
            Wend
        
        If RunningBuyQuantity > SellQuantity(x).Value2 Then
            Residual = SellQuantity(x).Value2 - RunningBuyQuantity
            UsedupResidual = BuyQuantity(y).Value2 - Residual
            RunningCost = RunningCost + (UsedupResidual * BuyPrice(y).Value2)
        End If
        
        RunningSales = SellPrice(x).Value2 * SellQuantity(x).Value2
        
        RunningProfit = RunningProfit + RunningSales - RunningCost
        
        RunningSales = 0
        RunningCost = 0
        
    Next x
    
    FIFO_PROFIT = RunningProfit
    
End Function
```